# How would I be able to create a loop for the following scatter plots?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to create a loop that will create multiple scatter plots like I have shown in the image. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGhdo.png]

```
pop = df['population']

racePctCols = df[['racepctblack', 'racePctWhite', 'racePctAsian', 
'racePctHisp']]
print(racePctCols)

fig, ([ax1,ax2],[ax3,ax4]) = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20,5)) # Draws a 2x2 
grid
ax1.set_title('Black')
sns.scatterplot(pop, racePctCols['racepctblack'], alpha = 0.2, ax=ax1)
ax2.set_title('White')
sns.scatterplot(pop, racePctCols['racePctWhite'], alpha = 0.2, ax=ax2)
ax3.set_title('Asian')
sns.scatterplot(pop, racePctCols['racePctAsian'], alpha = 0.2, ax=ax3)
ax4.set_title('Hispanic')
sns.scatterplot(pop, racePctCols['racePctHisp'], alpha = 0.2, ax=ax4)
```

Comment: what do you mean by create a loop that will create multiple scatter plots like the ones shown?  Are you trying to create one scatterplot per column of a dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try `zip` (forget about `pop` and `racePctCols`, `sns` is smart enough to handle that):

```
# the plotting columns
cols=['racepctblack', 'racePctWhite', 'racePctAsian', 'racePctHisp']

# to set the title   
titles = ['Black','White','Asian', 'Hispanic']

# no need to manually label the grids here
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2, figsize=(20,5)) # Draws a 2x2 

for col, title, ax in zip(cols, titles, axes.ravel()):
    ax.set_title(title)
    sns.scatterplot(x='population', y=col,
                    data=df, alpha = 0.2, ax=ax)
```

Comment: Thank you Quang. That worked a treat I appreciate the feedback and will look more into `zip`

Comment: I already have but because I'm new to stackoverflow it doesn't show up. It's the least I could do. You have worked wonders you absolute genius! :) Thank you once again. You've helped me and others in answering this question.